# Request mp4 file from server that requests a cookie

Tags: php, cookies, http-headers, html5-video

So I have a video tag

```
<video controls> 
     <source src="http://somewebsite/file.mp4" type="video/mp4" /> 
</video>
```

The server from `http://somewebsite/file.mp4` checks if the request headers have a specific cookie, else you get 403 forbidden.

How can I send that cookie? I tried curl proxy, but there are problems with seeking. Maybe a flash based player that can do requests to media with specific http headers, or another way? Please help!

Comment: Are you sure that's legal? There is a reason why the server requests a cookie.

Comment: For educational purposes only, and yes that's legal!